# filter JSON result by attribute if the obj. attribute is true with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to retrieve and filter JSON data with React.js and maybe hooks but I cant come with any good way to do it. Just now I have my JSON data local, so it does not come from restAPI or similar (for now)... and what Im trying is to create a menu with buttons that when I click on them I get filtered data. I know... it should not be very difficut to do it (cause Im doing it already in a veeeery basic way for a conditional that show different icones depending on if certain attribute is true.) but anyway im struggling with it.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {setState, useState} from 'react';

export const ByCourse = () => {
const projects = window.projects.aaData;
console.log('window.projects = ', projects);

return (
<div className="section-component">
  <h2 className="mt-2 mb-4">By Course</h2>

  <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link active" href="#">
        All
      </a>
    </li>
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#">
        Favorite
      </a>
    </li>
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#">
        Recent
      </a>
    </li>
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#">
        Assigned
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div className="container">

    {projects.map(project => {

      return(
        <div className="row">
          <div className="w-100">
            <div className="d-flex border mt-1 mb-1 p-3">
              <div className="col-1">
                {project.favorite ? <i className="fa fa-star"></i> : <i className="fa fa-star-o"></i>}
              </div>
              <div className="col-11">
                <div className="font-weight-bold"> {project.projectTitle}</div>
                <div className="font-weight-normal"> {project.ouName}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      )})}

  </div>
</div>
);};
```

and my data looks like this:

```
 projects = {"aaData":
 [
 {
   "index":0,
   "projectTitle":"123",
   "userTitle":"VVS-teknik grund",
   "ouName":"fertest1",
   "orgUnitId":1022,
   "projectId":2014,
   "favorite":false,
   "recent":false,
   "userAssigned":false,
   "projectStatus":"ACTIVE",
   "viewLink":"http://xxxxxx
 },
 {
   "index":1,
   "projectTitle":"AAA",
   "userTitle":"AAA",
   "ouName":"fertest1",
   "orgUnitId":1022,
   "projectId":2002,
   "favorite":false,
   "recent":true,
   "userAssigned":false,
   "projectStatus":"ACTIVE",
   "viewLink":"http://xxxxxx
 },
 {
   "index":2,
   "projectTitle":"Activity with image and text",
   "userTitle":"asdas",
   "ouName":"ferfer AB",
   "orgUnitId":1004,
   "projectId":1892,
   "favorite":false,
   "recent":false,
   "userAssigned":true,
   "projectStatus":"NEW",
   "viewLink":"http://xxxxxx"
}]
```

I tried using a solution from here: [Filtering JSON results in categories - React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262633/filtering-json-results-in-categories-react-hooks)
but I get a WEBPACK_1 ERROR and cant fix it...

Im also doing a very basic filtering here:

```
{project.favorite ? <i className="fa fa-star"></i> : <i className="fa fa-star-o"></i>}
```

and basically what Im looking for is:

if attribute "favorite" is true -> show results with attr favorite true
else
if attribute "recent" is true -> just show results with attribute recent == true
Thank you very much in advance, any help will be very very welcome.

Comment: just use ```Array.filter```

Comment: allriught! Im gonna check it out! :)

Comment: projects.filter(....).map(...)

Comment: The correct way is check it within the map

Comment: if you need to show them after state change, then you need to combine map and filter together, which named ```Array.reduce```

Comment: Can you please share the data in proper JSON format? Thanks

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Sure! let me fix that :)

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Should be fixed now :)

Comment: @FernandoLöpez, got it so basically you want from the array where `favorite OR recent: true`, put that object in results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example using `useState` to set a filter:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-turing-jd3ym?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had not understand how to make the "filteredProjects" and now is cristal clear!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the filtering or those functions is not about React.js. It's about JavaScript.

I will try go to be honest, i don't undestand anything about your problem. Could you please write only your problem?

Note: Don't mix the conditional keyword or something like that.
If you write the problem clearly we will (i) will help you.
Bonus: I refactor your code.

Here changes list:
1- I removed the unnecessary import
2- Seperate your code. Make component.
3- Indentation
4- Short condition (Fix for duplicate code)

```
import React from 'react';

const Project = data => (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="w-100">
      <div className="d-flex border mt-1 mb-1 p-3">
        <div className="col-1">
          <i className={data.favorite ? "fa fa-star" : "fa fa-star-o"} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-11">
          <div className="font-weight-bold"> {data.projectTitle}</div>
          <div className="font-weight-normal"> {data.ouName}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export const ByCourse = () => {
  const projects = window.projects.aaData;
  console.log('window.projects = ', projects);

  return (
    <div className="section-component">
      <h2 className="mt-2 mb-4">By Course</h2>

      <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link active" href="#">
            All
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Favorite
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Recent
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a className="nav-link" href="#">
            Assigned
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div className="container">
        {projects.map(project => <Project data={project} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the support and the approach to me in a very nice and good way!!! I really appreciate the help!! now is fixed! You are great!!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show the objects where `favorite OR recent: true`,

1) A simple way to do this is:

```js
let projects = {
  "aaData": [{
          "index": 0,
          "projectTitle": "123",
          "userTitle": "VVS-teknik grund",
          "ouName": "fertest1",
          "orgUnitId": 1022,
          "projectId": 2014,
          "favorite": true,
          "recent": false,
          "userAssigned": false,
          "projectStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
      },
      {
          "index": 1,
          "projectTitle": "AAA",
          "userTitle": "AAA",
          "ouName": "fertest1",
          "orgUnitId": 1022,
          "projectId": 2002,
          "favorite": false,
          "recent": true,
          "userAssigned": false,
          "projectStatus": "ACTIVE",
          "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
      },
      {
          "index": 2,
          "projectTitle": "Activity with image and text",
          "userTitle": "asdas",
          "ouName": "ferfer AB",
          "orgUnitId": 1004,
          "projectId": 1892,
          "favorite": false,
          "recent": false,
          "userAssigned": true,
          "projectStatus": "NEW",
          "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
      }
  ]
}

for (let iterator = 0; iterator < projects.aaData.length; iterator++) {
    if (projects.aaData[iterator].favorite || projects.aaData[iterator].recent) {
        console.log(projects.aaData[iterator])
    } else {
      continue;
    }
}
```

2) Other way to do this is:

```js
let projects = {
      "aaData": [{
              "index": 0,
              "projectTitle": "123",
              "userTitle": "VVS-teknik grund",
              "ouName": "fertest1",
              "orgUnitId": 1022,
              "projectId": 2014,
              "favorite": true,
              "recent": false,
              "userAssigned": false,
              "projectStatus": "ACTIVE",
              "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
          },
          {
              "index": 1,
              "projectTitle": "AAA",
              "userTitle": "AAA",
              "ouName": "fertest1",
              "orgUnitId": 1022,
              "projectId": 2002,
              "favorite": false,
              "recent": true,
              "userAssigned": false,
              "projectStatus": "ACTIVE",
              "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
          },
          {
              "index": 2,
              "projectTitle": "Activity with image and text",
              "userTitle": "asdas",
              "ouName": "ferfer AB",
              "orgUnitId": 1004,
              "projectId": 1892,
              "favorite": false,
              "recent": false,
              "userAssigned": true,
              "projectStatus": "NEW",
              "viewLink": "http://xxxxxx"
          }
      ]
    }

  let filteredArrayWithNull = projects.aaData.filter((object) => {
    return object.favorite || object.recent ?
            object : null
  })

  let finalFilteredArray = filteredArrayWithNull.filter((object) => object!=null)

  console.log(finalFilteredArray);
```

To read more about `filter()`; here is a comprehensive [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help, your firsts comments help me a lot to understand what I had to look for!! I really appreciate all the help and support! You are great!

Comment: @FernandoLöpez, No worries. Happy coding :)